# Angularjs upload image

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, multer

I'm trying to create an upload function using angularjs. I have watch and read few tutorials in the internet. Unfortunately all the tutorials are too complicated for me because I'm still new in this field.

```html
<form ng-submit="upload(currentUser())">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label>Car</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Perodua Myvi" class="form-control" ng-model="newCar" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label>Price(RM) per day</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" placeholder="80" class="form-control" ng-model="newPrice" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label>Business Area</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Universiti Malaysia Sabah" class="form-control" ng-model="businessArea" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label>Insert Car Image</label>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Image
                </button>-->
                    <input type="file"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Publish
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</form>
```

```js
app.controller('postadCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'auth',
    function($scope, auth) {

     $scope.currentUser = auth.currentUser;

        $scope.posts = [];

        $scope.upload = function(user) {
            $scope.posts.push({
             company_name: user,
                car_type: $scope.newCar,
                seaters: 5,
                price: $scope.newPrice,
                contact: 038880000,
                location: $scope.businessArea
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

So how do I do this in the simplest form and explanation? And how does my router and module will look like?
The output should look like this.
[image]

Comment: also, upload image to *where*?  Your `upload` function is only pushing data into an in memory array, which will disappear when the page is refreshed.

Comment: @Claies the code that I show has no problem/error. I use the currentUser() to get the authenticate user name. As you can see in the picture, Shsh is the name I get from currentUser().
I know I'm just pushing the data into the memory array because I don't know how to code it. Can you teach me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload file with angular material and angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761148/upload-file-with-angular-material-and-angular-js)